# parsing json by jquery's getJSON for twitter api search results not working

Tags: jquery, search, twitter, getjson

Problem : for a given query i try to parse the json from the twitter api results.

Codes at : http://jsfiddle.net/Nstnx/176/

Comment: Why are you doing two requests to the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm waaaay behind on this, and cwallenpoole should get any credit due for being *much* quicker , but here's a working demo -

http://jsfiddle.net/nkQ4Q/

Answer (score 5):

The data parameter has a `results` property. You want to iterate over that instead of over the data directly:

This

```
$.each( data, function( index, item ) {
```

Should be

```
$.each( data.results, function( index, item ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=50&q='ramlila'";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var items = [];      

        var twitterList = $( "<ul />" );
        $.each( data.results, function( index, item ) {
           alert(data.results[index].text);
            $( "<li />", { "text" : item.from_user} )
                .appendTo( twitterList );
        });
        $( "#output" ).fadeOut( "fast", function(){
            $( this ).empty()
                .append( twitterList )
                .fadeIn( "slow" );            
        });


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nstnx/182/